# Devex AspxListbox

Tags: asp.net, collections, devexpress

I get error on   List newlst = lst.SelectedItems.Cast().ToList()**
It says Unable to cast object of type 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ListEditItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'
here is my code:

```
 int id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToInt();
        ASPxDropDownEdit dde = (ASPxDropDownEdit)FormViewProjectBasicInfo.FindControl("ASPxDropDownEdit1");
        ASPxListBox lst = (ASPxListBox)dde.FindControl("listBox");
        List<ListItem> newlst = lst.SelectedItems.Cast<ListItem>().ToList();
        List<ProjectDependency> dp = DataContext.ProjectDependencies.Where(m => m.MasterProjectID == id).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < newlst.Count; i++)
        {
            bool found = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < dp.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dp[j].DependentProjectID==newlst[i].Value.ToInt())
                {

                    break;
                }

                    ProjectDependencyObjectDataSource.InsertParameters["masterprojectid"].DefaultValue =Request.QueryString["id"];
                    ProjectDependencyObjectDataSource.InsertParameters["dependentprojectid"].DefaultValue =newlst[i].Value;
                    ProjectDependencyObjectDataSource.Insert();

            }
        }
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Did you asked in DevExpress?

Comment: yes i asked and waiting till they reply,I fixed it yesterday but unfortunately i didnt save now i cant remember how i did it lol

Comment: @peterprova: _What part of the error don't you understand_?

Comment: He wants the correct cast

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CargocultProgramming.aspx

Comment: Have you thought about creating a new instance of `List` and moving your objects from `ASPxDropDownEdit` one by one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getting the error because DevExpress' controls are separate from the regular ASP.NET controls (which `ListItem` is a part of).

Based on your usage of `newlst` in your code, you have no need to cast the items from their original type as [`ListEditItem`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsListEditItemMembersTopicAll) has a `Value` property. You just need to define your instance using the proper type and use the original type in the call to `OfType()` (which is only needed to get the `IEnumerable<T>`):

```
List<ListEditItem> newlst = lst.SelectedItems.OfType<ListEditItem>().ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think `SelectedItems` implements `IEnumerable<T>` for any `T`.

Comment: Thanks Justin,It doesn't have .ToList() option

Comment: @SLaks - Guess I should read all of the documentation before answering. Never used the DevExpress toolkit. Seems like something they would've implemented by now.

Comment: @peterprova - I just updated my answer. Needed to add a call to `OfType()` to get the `IEnumerable<T>` to call `ToList()` on. You're still using the original types though.

Comment: I changed it as lst.SelectedItems.Cast<ListEditItem>().ToList()

Comment: It is how it should be, the Cast says what you are casting, not what you cast TO, that is the ToList() for.

Comment: @AnnArbor87 - Please read the documentation for `Cast<T>()`. There's a reason the parameter is called `TResult`. It's the type you want the cast to result in...not what you're casting from. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable_members(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks guys.It's been fixed.Special Thanks to Justin Niessner that gave me final Hint:)

Answer (score 0):

As the error **clearly** states, that is a collection of `ListEditItem` objects.
You cannot magically convert them to the unrelated `ListItem` class; you can only castan object to a class that it is actually an instance of.

Comment: @AnnArbor87: He needs to **understand** the problem.  Once he understands what's going on, he can find the correct solution in 30 seconds.  Give a man a fish...

Comment: @peterprova: And therefore what?

Comment: HE knows the error is Unable to cast object of type 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ListEditItem' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' so that casting is wrong

Comment: @AnnArbor87: Yes.  He needs to understand **why** and **how** it's wrong.

Comment: @peterprova: What don't you understand?

Comment: Its not about Understanding,I need to fix it:)

Comment: @peterprova: **Wrong**!  Programming is _all about understanding_.  If you don't understand what you're doing, you have no hope of success.

Comment: Ok,now give me a solution pls

Comment: Well so following @SLaks way of making you understand, *lst* is a list of ListEditItem so start checking there

Comment: Sooooo...the cast is wrong @peterprova Check how to make proper casts

Comment: @peterprova: In particular, you need to figure out what type to cast it to.